# How to persist nested Doctrine Entities correctly

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework3, persist

I'm using Doctrine 2 in Zendframework 3.

I got an Order object with an 1:n relation to OrderAdditions which has a 1:1 Relation to OrderItems.

In the Order entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="LwsProject\Entity\OrderAddition", mappedBy="order", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 */
protected $orderAdditions;

 public function addOrderAdditions($orderAdditions) {
    if($orderAdditions instanceof OrderAddition) {
        $this->orderAdditions->add($orderAdditions);
        $orderAdditions->setOrder($this);
    }else if($orderAdditions instanceof ArrayCollection){
        foreach($orderAdditions as $orderAddition){
            $this->orderAdditions->add($orderAddition);
            $orderAddition->setOrder($this);
        }
    }
    return $this->orderAdditions;
}

public function removeOrderAdditions($orderAdditions) {
    if($orderAdditions instanceof OrderAddition) {
        $this->orderAdditions->removeElement($orderAdditions);
    }else if($orderAdditions instanceof ArrayCollection){
        foreach($orderAdditions as $orderAddition){
            $this->orderAdditions->removeElement($orderAddition);
        }
    }
    return $this->orderAdditions;
}
```

In the OrderAddition:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="\LwsProject\Entity\OrderItem", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, fetch="EAGER")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="order_item_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $orderItem;
```

And in the OrderItem:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="LwsProject\Entity\OrderAddition")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="order_addition_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $orderAddition;
```

Im Creating a new OrderAddition with a new OrderItem for several posted Items from a form.

```
// $order is either a new Order() or an entity from database.
$orderAddition = new OrderAddition();
//setting Data from post
$orderItem = new OrderItem();
//settign data from post     
$orderAddition->setOrderItem($orderItem);
$orderItem->setOrderAddition($orderAddition);
$order->addOrderAdditions($orderAddition);
```

When I'm flushing while using `$em->persist($order)` with a new Order() everything gets persisted as expected, when im using an existing Order from the database i get:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'order_item_id' cannot be null
```

Comment: "Column 'order_item_id' cannot be null" Definetly it's null and i can't see anything related to order_item_id.  Can you share your order item entity?

Comment: Nvm saw it ☺ So you sure there's something kind id right?

Comment: And did you wrote your own repositories? Cause i just found this: https://gist.github.com/cakper/1446386

Comment: Its working now after i added mappedBy and inversedBy to the associated fields in OrderAddition and OrderItem. But i dont know why that leads to be wokring with a new Order object and onyl fails with an existing one

Comment: Because it doesn't retrieve data from database so order_item_id is null. And your database reject to process data because that field can not be null.